# Scanf allow space between words

Tags: c

I am try to read in some data with an id followed by firstname lastname from a text file and I cannot seem to get scanf to allow the space.

input may look like:
123456 FirstName LastName

`scanf("%d%s", &id, fullName)` doesn't work because it cuts off at the space between first and last name. I would like to have 'first last' in one string (preferrably without concat because there are instances where the last name is not included).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the set notation to specify a set of allowable characters in your name, and explicitly allow spaces:

```
scanf("%d %[ a-zA-Z]", &id, fullName);
```

Here, `[]` specifies a set of characters to allow (see [man 3 scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)), and within there there is a space, `a-z`, which means "all lower-case characters" and `A-Z` which means "all upper-case characters.

All that said, you should specify a maximum width, to avoid overflowing your buffer. For example:

```
char fullName[64]; // allocate 64-byte array and set to 0
scanf("%d %63[ a-zA-Z]", &id, fullName);
```

Note the use of 63 instead of 64; the man page notes that it will read in the number of characters specified, and *then* a NULL-terminator:

> String input conversions store a null terminator ('\0') to mark the end of the input; the maximum field width does not include this terminator.

Comment: Dan meant that the expression in `[]` is called regular expression. You can google it - there's planty of info for RegExps.

Comment: @MichaelSazonov: What's in the `[ ]` isn't a regular expression, it's simply a *set* as Dan has stated. man page: *"Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified **set of accepted  characters**"*

Comment: @AusCBloke You are totally right! My mistake. It is just a part of regexps.

Comment: Answer could be even better if it recommend checking `scanf()` results.  Added thought: With `%[ a-zA-Z]`, wonder about names like "Kareem Abdul-Jabbar",  "Peter O'Toole" and "John C. Smith".  Maybe `%[ a-zA-Z'.-]`?

Answer (score 3):

scanf doesnt allow spaces in it
you can use gets() or preferably fgets() function.
gets copies whole line into the string
while fgets copies the number of character specified

if you want to do it with scanf use %[^\n] instead of %s

Comment: This just isn't true. You can scan in spaces with `scanf()`, and using `fgets()` would still require him to parse out the fields of his line with something like `sscanf()` anyway.

Comment: with %s you cant scan two word while[^\n] would work but i think fgets is much better

Comment: he doesnt need to parse he needs both name in one string only

Comment: anyway i am a newbie may be i know less than you

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

- To read in characters up until the end of the line, you can replace the format specifier `%s` with one like `%[^\n]`, which simply means read up until a `\n` is encountered.
- An alternative is to use use `fgets()` to read the string after you've read your `int`. This has the added benefit of preventing buffer overflows, as you have to pass to `fgets()` the maximum amount of characters to be read.