# Code not letting me input and ends immediately

Tags: c, arrays, string, clion, sentence

I have created a function that reverses all the words in a sentence, meaning that if the input is "Hello World" the output is supposed to be "World Hello". The code below is the function.

```
char*  reversesentence(char sent[]) {
  int lth = strlen(sent);
  int i;

  for(i = lth -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(sent[i] == ' ') {
        sent[i] = '\0'; 
        printf("%s ", &(sent[i]) + 1); 
    }
  }

  printf("%s", sent);
}
```

In the main I am trying to ask the user for the sentence and calling the function in the main.

```
  int main(void)
  {
    char sentence[2000];

    printf("Please enter the sentence you want to be reversed.\n");

    scanf("%s", sentence);
    reversesentence(sentence);
    printf("%s", sentence);
  }
```

It seems that the array is only storing the first word of the sentence only.

Output:

```
Please enter the sentence you want to be reversed.
hello my name is 
hellohello
Process finished with exit code 0`
```

Can someone help me fix this please? Searched online and found nothing useful.

Comment: Use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead of `scanf`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanf allow space between words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437919/scanf-allow-space-between-words)

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` stops reading when it occurs whitespace,tabs or newline.

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer
>   must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the
>   input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added
>   automatically. **The input string stops at white space or at the maximum
>   field width, whichever occurs first.**

Thus you are not reading the entire string as you input.

Try using `fgets` as below.

```
fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);
```

---

> Note `fgets` appends `\n` to end of the string.  [see how to trim the
>   new line from
>   fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Comment: Tried using it now, but it didn't give me time to enter the input. 
Output: 

Please enter the sentence you want to be reversed.



Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @FrancescaAttard you also forgot to `return` from `reversesentence()`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems

- as it was already said you only read one word using *scanf*
- `reversesentence` just replace all spaces by a null character, so even you read a full line you cut it at the first space. so if you enter "hello world" the result will be "hello", and if you enter " hello world" the result will be an empty string

The simple way is to read words using *scanf* **in a loop** until it returns EOF, memorizing them, to at the end produce the list of words returned

For instance :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  size_t len = 0;
  char * result = 0;
  char word[256];

  while (scanf("%256s", word) != EOF) {
    if (result == 0) {
      result = strdup(word);
      len = strlen(word);
    }
    else {
      size_t l = strlen(word);
      char * r = malloc(len + l + 2);

      strcpy(r, word);
      r[l] = ' ';
      strcpy(r + l + 1, result);
      free(result);
      result = r;
      len += l + 1;
    }
  }

  puts(result);
  free(result);
  return 0;
}
```

The reading finishes at the end of the input (^d under a linux shell), the words can be given on several lines.

With the input

```
hello world
how
are you
?
```

that prints

> ? you are how world hello